# check package revision history

Tags: package-management

I want to review which package versions have been available in repositories at certain date. For example I want to know for the 'dirvish' package what subsequent versions have been available from repositories and what date that version was introduced. Where can I find that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the information on the website, for instance:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dirvish/+publishinghistory